# New Notifications Since Last Seen (django)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

Right now I'm using this view in order to inform the user that their question is just answered,

```
def notifications(request):
answers = Answer.objects.filter(question__user=request.user).order_by('-id')
....
```

But this is just a plain html text notification. I wants to make it more dynamic by notifying them the number of new notifications they have since their last seen, as we see on social networks.

How can I do that?

Please help me with this code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you checking if it is a new notification?

Comment: @TimmSimpkins  Sir, I'm doing nothing except if Question of a user is answered then i'm simply ordering the answer by negative of id for that user in Notification as shown in code above. This way a new notification (which is actually a answer) will stay at the top! I was wondering how can I tell them about the new notifications they have since they opened the notification page, as we see on social networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a record somewhere of the last time the person checked their notifications.  You also need to keep the time the answer was created.  Once you have those two things, you do a query something like this:

```
lastchecked = (query the last time the person checked their notifications.  This should be a datetime object.)

notification_count = Answer.objects.filter(question__user=request.user, created__gte=lastchecked).count()
```

Comment: Wow, seems a great way of doing this without writing too much code. Thank you very much Sir @TimmSimpkins